# How can I get values from a TypeORM property decorator

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeorm

```js
import { PrimaryColumn, Column } from 'typeorm';

export class LocationStatus {
  @PrimaryColumn({ name: 'location_id' })
  locationId: string;

  @Column({ name: 'area_code', type: 'int' })
  areaCode: number;
}
```

I spent the past few hours trying to figure it out how to retrieve a name property value `location_id` and `area_code` from a property decorator `@Column()`, but no luck. I'm not sure whether it's even possible to get a list of properties or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from the `typeorm` source code (here: [1](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/d9f5581b22c4cccfab55ee23fad699e1c8acadf8/src/decorator/columns/Column.ts#L139), [2](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/d9f5581b22c4cccfab55ee23fad699e1c8acadf8/src/index.ts#L167), [3](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/e4de0403e1f666639c0198e216409f997121c1e8/src/platform/BrowserPlatformTools.template#L18), [4](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/490ad0d424e674de5be38b0c3bc83b9a14a383a5/src/platform/PlatformTools.ts#L22)) you can access all kinds of stuff through global variable `typeormMetadataArgsStorage` (like `window.typeormMetadataArgsStorage` or `global.typeormMetadataArgsStorage`). Explore it, and I believe you'll find what you're seeking for with something like that:

```js
const global_context = ??? // depends on your environment
const property_to_look_for = `areaCode`
const name = global_context.typeormMetadataArgsStorage
  .columns
  .filter(col => col.propertyName === property_to_look_for && col.target === LocationStatus)
  .options
  .name
console.log(name)
```

**UPDATED**

For those of you who are currently using `Nest` like myself, here's what I've done so far.

```js
import { getMetadataArgsStorage, InsertResult } from 'typeorm';

export class PinLocationStatusRepository extends Repository<PinLocationStatus> {
  // Column names in this array, the value should not be modified.
  // For instance, the location_id value "location_ko_01" won't be changed.
  private static immutableColumnNames = ['location_id', ...]; 

  private static mutableColumnFound(name: string): boolean {
    return PinLocationStatusRepository.immutableColumnNames.every(colName => colName !== name);
  }

  savePinLocation(state: PinLocationStatus): Promise<InsertResult> {
    const columns = getMetadataArgsStorage()
     .columns.filter(({ target }) => target === PinLocationStatus)
     .map(({ options, propertyName }) => (!options.name ? propertyName : options.name))
     .reduce((columns, name) => {
       if (PinLocationStatusRepository.mutableColumnFound(name)) {
         columns.push(name);
       }
       return columns;
    }, []);

    return this.createQueryBuilder()
      .insert()
      .into(PinLocationStatus)
      .values(state)
      .orUpdate({ overwrite: columns }) // ['area_code']
      .execute();
  }
}
```

1. Extract the column name from the `@Column()` decorator.
2. Filter out some column names where the values have to remain the same.
3. Pass the columns variable into `overwrite` property.

You will get a correct result unless the `area_code` is an immutable column.

Comment: [`globalThis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis) would be appropriate.

Comment: @AluanHaddad, thanks... but is it really universally accepted way by now?`Implementation progress` section on the *MDN* is not so optimistic.

Comment: True. My inclination would be to polyfill it but it's not a feature that can be polyfilled.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. I'd like to edit your answer, but the queue is currently full.

Comment: I've just added the code snippet below your answer. Once again, thank you very much!

Comment: @JeffMinsungKim, you're welcome. Accepted you edit, but I think it'd be nice if you explain: 1) what exactly are you trying to achieve with this snippet 2) what is the issue with immutable columns 3) and maybe remove `Promise`, as it seems to be unrelated to the part of code you've posted.

Comment: @x00, I've fixed the edit. I've also added the return statement, so kept the `Promise` as a return type.